# Android - What is the standard way to implement the tab now?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie of Android. I have searched for hours but I see many different approaches and many is deprecated.

I know this question is silly, but I really need someone's help.

What is the standard way that most developers do when they want to implement the tab, please give some informations.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say probably [`TabLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) adds [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), providing a tab implementation that matches the [material design guidelines for tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html). A complete walkthrough of how to implement Tabs and `ViewPager` can be found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ).